# I have encountered an logical error about fetching data from laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

### I have two models Client and Group.

This is many to many relationships where the client belongs to many groups and groups have more than one client.
I want to get all the clients that not already belong to a group and pass it to the view.

Group Model:

```
public function clients() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Client', 'client_group', 'group_id', 'client_id');
    }
```

Client model:

```
public function documents() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'client_document', 'client_id', 'document_id');
    }
```

GroupsController.php

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        $clients = Client::all()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        return view('backend.groups.edit', compact('group', 'id', 'clients'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want clients that are not part of a group. Essentially, you need to query relationship absence:

```
$clients = App\Client::doesntHave('groups')->get();
```

If you want to have the ability to add additional where clauses:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

...

$clients = App\Client::whereDoesntHave('groups', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('active', '=', true);
})->get();
```

For more information see [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)